# Sorting arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

is there is a function in matlab that sort array in descending order and reurns the indices of them?

```
a=[88 33 99 2 11 32]
```

then

```
b=[3 1 2 6 5 4]
```

Comment: "help sort" command helps you a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
[q b] = sort(a,'descend')
```

in b array will be what you want.