# sort data from large to small

Tags: matlab, sorting

In a data set how can I sort data from large to small?
using `sort` data become from small to large:

```
a=[1 3 5 2 6];
b=sort(a);
b=[1 2 3 5 6];
```

but I want `b` :

```
b=[6 5 3 2 1]
```

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802512/sorting-arrays-in-matlab) [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820130/sort-matlab-array-in-descending-order) [word](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) [...](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/sorting-data-in-matlab/)

Comment: A `doc sort` would have got you there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html. The sort function can take a mode parameter.

```
b = sort(a) % 'ascend' by default

b = sort(a, 'descend') % sort data from large to small
```

Answer (score 4):

[Yuan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21779425/2586922) is the way to go.

Some slightly more hackish alternatives:

```
b = -sort(-a);
b = fliplr(sort(a));
```